# django mysql connection don't respect databases settings in settings.py

Tags: python, mysql, django

This is my database connection string in settings.py.

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": os.getenv("DB_PORT", '3306'),
        "NAME": os.getenv("DB_DATABASE", 'sm'),
        "USER": os.getenv("DB_USER", 'root'),
        "PASSWORD": os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD", ''),
    }
}
```

As above the host specified `127.0.0.1`

but when I run python manage.py runserver database connection error with the wrong hostname.

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user
> 'root'@'**172.18.0.1**' (using password: NO)")

As you can see I wrote hostname **127.0.0.1** but in the project, it is connecting **172.18.0.1**

I really appreciate, it if someone gives me an answer to this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: can you try with host -> `0.0.0.0`

Comment: @hackaholic, I am using windows, and 0.0.0.0 port is not working on windows.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the error message. It is not saying that you are connecting **to** 172.18.0.1. It is saying you are trying to connect **from** 172.18.0.1.